# Firebase Crashlytics not showing event logs

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I have been using firebase for android for 1 year now. For last few days i have noticed that firebase crashlytics on console not showing event logs as they were shown previously like this

[image]

It see all the screens the user went through right before a crash happened. It was really helpful. Now it is not showing in console. No sub tabs are visible in log tab.

Does firebase remove the feature ? or i am missing some property to enable to make it visible on console.

Comment: If the Firebase console is not working the way you expect, or you have feedback about it, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: did u got the answer ????