# Firebase Crashlytics not showing Logs after SDK upgrade in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

My app is using `Crashlytics` which is moved from Fabrics to Firebase `Crashlytics`. My problem is that I recently upgraded firebase `Crashlytics` and after this upgrade there is no "Logs" displaying with crash report. I cross checked all settings and code but couldn't find any possible reason.
It was working properly before upgrade. Now all crashes are being reported properly as all the information such as "Stack Trace", "Keys" are as before but "Logs" section is empty.
My question may be an "iOS Duplicate" of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407966/firebase-crashlytics-not-showing-event-logs) question. Anybody please tell me if there is any part of code I'm missing to get this "Logs" data.

Here is the code I setup in my AppDelegate for configuration :

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, are you capturing log messages with `Crashlytics.crashlytics().log()`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#add-logs

Comment: no !! I know its kinda silly but I can't figure out where to add this line exactly.

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation at that link I sent? It describes how you can use the function to capture log messages. If you used to use `CLSLogv` or `CLSNSLogv`, you should replace those with calls to `Crashlytics.crashlytics().log()`.